# How can I list Ubuntu disks by a unique identifier?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS inside a VM running on VMware Workstation 8.0.4.

When I try to view the disks attached to the machine by their ID nothing shows up but the CD-ROM drive. I listing the disk by running `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id`

I need a way to uniquely identify the disk so I create a ZFS pool to test. They recommend disk by-id but anything would work I guess.

Any idea how I can get something to work?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Also running the following (as root), will print the UUID of a certain partition:

```
blkid /dev/sda0
```

Comment: It only shows me the IDs of partitions, I need IDs or physical disks. The disks are unformatted. I am starting to think this problem may be something with VMware.

Comment: Physical disk's don't have UUID AFAIK.

Comment: I found this Suse support article that I think might explain what my problem is. http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002966 When I get off work I will give this a try.